# what is the reason for OpenGL rotated textures when cube mapping?

Tags: opengl

In the process of learning how to implement enviorment mapping in OpenGL using GLSL shaders I stumbled upon some confusion.

I used 6 different images for each face of the cube map, and generated geometry for a 'skybox', a simple cube centered around the origin that surrounds the entire scene. I made sure I was generating the mesh currently and that the code that loads the targa images is not rotating the pixels.

When rendering, the vertex shader just copies the vertex position over to the fragment and I used the interpelated vertex position as the (s,t,r) cordinates to sample from the cube map.

*Vertex Shader*

```
#version 430

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;

out vec3 ReflectDir;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
    ReflectDir = VertexPosition;
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

*Fragment Shader*

```
#version 430

uniform samplerCube CubeMapTex;

in vec3 VertexPosition;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
    FragColor = texture(CubeMapTex, VertexPosition);
}
```

**I noticed the textures on the sides of the cube map are rotated 180 degrees.**

[image: On the left is the texture I used for the positive x face of the cube, and on the right is the rendered result]

Then after trying to figure out what is going on, I found [this tutorial](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cube_map_ogl_tutorial.html) and figured out that OpenGL is unwrapping the cube map in a somewhat of a strage way. The following image shows the conclusion I arived at displaying the (s,t) axis for all 6 faces of the unwrapped cube.

[image]

So my actual question is **What is the reasoning behind this kind of implementation?** is there an explenation on why OpenGL handles cube mapping this way?

Comment: Origin should be lower-left, but there are a few things that can change that.  What is the origin in the texture you are loading? Targa files, quite notably, let you specify different origins, and most image loaders use upper-left.  What is your MVP matrix?  You can easily change the origin using the MVP matrix.

Comment: The origin is (0,0) for all 6 images, and the MVP is not the cuase either, what is seen in the rendered image is a camera positioned near the negative x face looking at the positive x face and a perspective projection with a 70.0 degrees field of view. Model matrix is an Identity matrix, so the origin of the cube is in (0,0,0) aswell.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the OpenGL cubemap specification is weird. As far as I can tell the cubemap texturing rules were copied in verbatim from the rules of RenderMan (you know, the software developed by Pixar for rendering their stuff). So ultimately you'd have to ask the guys over at Pixar, why they choose that particular rule set.

An explanation often thrown around, but also very wrong one is, that cubemaps have their pixel origin in the upper left of their respective cube faces (whatever upper left is) and use a left hand coordinate system. But if you look closely at it, thats not the case.

A much more likely explanation is, that for cubemaps it made sense to have the pixel origin to be in the positive/positive quadrant of the basis plane into which each cube face is coplanar and aligned to.

Either way I suggest you don't suggest to think to much about it, since, like everything in math, you can freely choose how to make things work, as long as your ruleset is somehow made consistent with the rest of the system.

Comment: Cubemap's origin is lower left both in DirectX and OpenGL.

Comment: @Nikos: Yes, that's what I wrote.